# If I'm making a utility app for iPhone, should the flipside info be stored in the AppDelegate class?

Tags: iphone, utility

I don't really like using plists (I know I should get used to it, but I haven't yet).  Is that what the app delegate can be used for, getting info between the two?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `NSUserDefaults`, for the standard types of utility apps as described in [Apple's Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html).